# mysqli_multi_query command out of sync error - not inserting into DB

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to use the mysqli_multi_query function on the code below but being hit with this error:

Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

```
// add call stats to incoming nodes
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `" . node_name_formatter($i_route) . "` ";
        $sql .= "            (`timeperiod`, ";
        $sql .= "             `exchange_id`, ";
        $sql .= "             `calls_in`) ";
        $sql .= "VALUES      ('" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time) . "', ";
        $sql .= "             '$exchange_id', ";
        $sql .= "             '1') ";
        $sql .= "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ";
        $sql .= "             `calls_in` = `calls_in`+1;";

// add call stats to outgoing nodes
        $sql .= "INSERT INTO `" . node_name_formatter($o_route) . "` ";
        $sql .= "            (`timeperiod`, ";
        $sql .= "             `exchange_id`, ";
        $sql .= "             `calls_out`) ";
        $sql .= "VALUES      ('" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time) . "', ";
        $sql .= "             '$exchange_id', ";
        $sql .= "             '1') ";
        $sql .= "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ";
        $sql .= "             `calls_out` = `calls_out`+1";

       // echo $sql . '<br><br>';
        mysqli_multi_query($connection, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
```

I am doing this query just as it says on the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php). Also is it better to use this function or to carry out 2 seperate queries the normal mysqli_query way?

Comment: It's because there's a typo in the SQL - you have a closing bracket after each `+1`, but no matching opening bracket.

Comment: Thanks, after correcting this, I am now getting this error:

Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Comment: That sounds like there's another command already running. You might need to add a little extra code.

Comment: It's great that you use `mysqli_multi_query` so it only takes `exchange_id='); DROP TABLE route; DROP TABLE users; DROP TABLE transactions; --` etc. to destroy your database. Thanks! (psst - you should REALLY use prepared statements and bind variables, or you can expect to be hacked/someone to destroy your site as soon as they find out)

Answer (score 0):

Update as

```
// add call stats to incoming nodes
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `" . node_name_formatter($i_route) . "` ";
        $sql .= "            (`timeperiod`, ";
        $sql .= "             `exchange_id`, ";
        $sql .= "             `calls_in`) ";
        $sql .= "VALUES      ('" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time) . "', ";
        $sql .= "             '$exchange_id', ";
        $sql .= "             '1') ";
        $sql .= "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ";
        $sql .= "             `calls_in` = `calls_in`+1;";

// add call stats to outgoing nodes
        $sql .= "INSERT INTO `" . node_name_formatter($o_route) . "` ";
        $sql .= "            (`timeperiod`, ";
        $sql .= "             `exchange_id`, ";
        $sql .= "             `calls_out`) ";
        $sql .= "VALUES      ('" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time) . "', ";
        $sql .= "             '$exchange_id', ";
        $sql .= "             '1') ";
        $sql .= "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ";
        $sql .= "             `calls_out` = `calls_out`+1;";

       // echo $sql . '<br><br>';
        mysqli_multi_query($connection, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
```

you have to loop through the result using mysqli_next_result to get result of each query.

Check here for more about the error [Commands out of sync](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/commands-out-of-sync.html)